# Install applications non-graphical via script

Tags: shell-script, debian

I'd like to install an application using a standard bash- or shell-script, in order to deploy the application on several servers without a user interaction.

To give an example, let's say I'd like to install [Pi Hole](https://pi-hole.net), which is pretty easy to install but it will [open a graphical setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GJ2Jqk8wD4) in order to install all components. When installing this application via a script the installation will fail or it'll be not working due to a lack of information.

Is there a way to skip graphical setups like this in Debian and provide a configuration file to provide the needed information while the setup process?

[image]

Comment: If it's using the standard Debian installer, then https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed will work... Or `debconf-set-selections ` if it's after the install phase. Not an answer because that's essentially throwing the manual at you.

Comment: For non-interactive install you can set environment variable `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before running `apt-get install`. It will choose default values than.

Comment: Edit the functions under https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/master/automated%20install/basic-install.sh

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to disable the debconf questions, all you need to do is set the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive`:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install foo bar baz
```

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html) has the information you are looking for. It is going to vary on a software to software basis. I had previously misread the question as if you needed an unattended pihole install. As mentioned by user derobert, this is not much of a solution. Good Luck!

<strike>Create `/etc/pihole/setupVars.conf` with the variables you want as [outlined here.](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/what-is-setupvars-conf-and-how-do-i-use-it/3533)</strike>

After you have created the `setupVars.conf` to your specification, you can run:

```
curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash /dev/stdin --unattended
```

This should install pihole without needing additional input. It is up to you if you want to create a script that will create the `setupVars.conf` or copy the first one you create for new installs. Do not forget to look through the [documentation](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/master/README.md). Good luck!